# Hibernate Basic: how to query when there is a composite id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a domain object say, SalesOrder which has a composite id called id, made of salesOrder id and repid which is contained in another class called SalesOrderID(which is serializable and implements equals and hashcode)

my question is when i want to query SalesOrder,
session.createSQLQuery("FROM SalesOrder where id=:soID")

and soID is populated with salesorder id and repid. this failes no matter what.

can anyone please help me?

thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than "this fails"?  What exactly is it saying?  Are you getting back 0 objects?  Are you getting a Hibernate Exception?

Answer (score 2):

It most likely fails because you're trying to create an **SQL** query. You should be using **HQL** instead:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from SalesOrder so where so.id=:id");
 query.setParameter("id", salesOrderID);
 query.list();
```

If this was a typo in your question and you are indeed using **createQuery()** method then please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Like ChssPly76 said, it's because you're creating a SQL query.  You can do this with a SQL query if you want, but you'll have to use database table columns, and you'll have to map the result back to an entity.  Best bet is to just use HQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had an incorrect mapping in the database beans class. Sorry for all the trouble, learned my lesson, apologize for wasting your time.